# Where should we place HBM files?

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a team of 5 to 8 people and our project is using Hibernate (ORM) but we are facing some problems related to HBM files and there respective VOs (Value Objects). Actually we all are working on different modules and we all are creating HBM files and there respective VOs as per our module (so we have our HBM files and VOs specific to our module). If common table is used in more than one module then we have multiple HBM file and their VOs for that single table. So should we place all the HBM files anf VOs to a specific location or keep them module specific even if we have multiple HBMs and VOs. Please suggest the GOOD or BAD practice as well.

Thanks

Comment: You should look at revision control, I presume it isn't there

Comment: Hi Nayan Thanks for your response but please guide be about the GOOD and BAD approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a `common project` that will contain all DAO related stuff. Each module/project will include that commonDAO project in its classpath to perform hibernate and database related operations. This will overcome HBM files duplicacy and ease to maintain code.

Comment: Hi Imran thanks for your response but there might be some mapping related work like JOINS, one to many, many to one, etc. in that case i think this will cause some problems

Comment: All those joins, one to many can be handled by hibernate. You can also use HBM queries to do joins etc

Answer (score 1):

From the query it seems each module has its own data access. If its not very complex, you can put all the data access in separate module. A project can have multiple modules but should have one place for data access.

- As suggested, you can have a DAO module which is only doing to Data related operations.
  Packages can be used to identify different DAO types.
- The common DAO should be kept simple. Business Logic should not go in that. Logic should be handled at a higher level.

Other than that :-

- Your project should be properly structured i.e. packages should be clearly defined.

> module1/src/../com/../../bl
>   module2/src/../com/../../b0
>
> dataacess/src/../com/../../bl
>   dataacess/src/../com/../../bo

- Dependencies should be clearly extrapolated. If you have one DAO module then DAO should be independent. Other Modules should depend on DAO. If its java you can use maven to do this.

Finally its the choice we make. There will be lot of best practices. You should choose what suits best in your scenario. In the end it should be simple and manageable in future.